# laravel5.1 firstOrFail() doesn't trigger 404

Tags: php, eloquent, http-status-code-404, laravel-5.1

As far as I know using firstOrFail() in laravel5.1 without catching the exception results in a 404 error.
My controller code:

```
 public function getTicket($id = null)
{
    $validator = Validator::make(compact('id'),[
        'id' => 'required|regex:/^[1-9]\d*$/',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) 
       dd("no");

   $tickets = Auth::user()->tickets()->where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();

   dd($tickets);
}
```

When I use a not existing id of ticket I just get this error:

> ModelNotFoundException in Builder.php line 157: No query results for
>   model [App\ticket].

How to trigger a 404 error page? As laravel doc told me

> If the exception is not caught, a 404 HTTP response is automatically
>   sent back to the user[...]

this shoud be done in my case.[laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent)